# post send long string over to my server is not working

Tags: post, angular

On the client side I am sending a message that a user creates to my server.  To send the message I am using the following code on the client side:

```
this.http.post(
    'http://192.168.1.100:3000/message',
    'at=' + data.res.rows.item(0).fb_at + '&j=' + data.res.rows.item(0).j + '&m=this is a long 5000 character max message a user can send.', {
        headers: headers
    }
)
```

The 'm' parameter is where the message is being sent. This post though is not coming through on my server. If I remove the 'm' param then it does go through? Something is wrong with the 'm' param then I think. How can I pass a long string to my server?

Comment: Dump out the URL to see what is being sent - there may be embedded quotes.

Comment: Do you have a message in the browser? Can you see the request in the Network tab of dev tools?